# Self-created fadeIn() function not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create the `fadeIn()` function using Javascript. I am having trouble, when I click the `fadeIn` button, it does not perform a `fadeIn` animation, instead I have to click it several times to fadeIn. Would anyone know how I can fix this issue?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsePz/1/)**

```
// Created a jQuery like reference
function $(selector) { 
    if (!(this instanceof $)) return new $(selector); // if new object is not defined, return new object
    this.selector = selector; // setting selector attribute
    this.node = document.querySelector(this.selector); // finds single element from the DOM
};

var fInFrom = 0, fOutFrom = 10;

$.prototype.fadeIn = function() {
    var target = this.node,
        newSetting = fInFrom / 10;

    // Set Default styles for opacity   
    target.style.display = 'block';
    target.style.opacity = newSetting;

    // fadeInFrom will increment by 1
    fInFrom++;

    var loopTimer = setTimeout('this.fadeIn', 50);

    if (fInFrom === 10) {
        target.style.opacity = 1;
        clearTimeout(loopTimer);
        fInFrom = 0;
        return false;
    }

    return this;
}

$('#fadeIn').node.addEventListener('click', function() {
    $('#box').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is your problem:

```
setTimeout('this.fadeIn', 50)
```

That will set a timeout to evaluate the expression `this.fadeIn` in the global scope in approximately 50 milliseconds from the current time. There's two problems with that:

1. It's in the global scope; `this` is `window`, not an instance of `$`, so `this.fadeIn` is `undefined`.
2. Even if it were resolved correctly, you're only evaluating `this.fadeIn`; you're not calling it. You would need to use `this.fadeIn()` for it to do anything. (If you do that with the current code, this will reveal your first problem.)

To solve this, pass not a string but a function that does what you want it to do. You might naïvely do this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    this.fadeIn();
}, 50);
```

Unfortunately, while we now have lexical scoping for variables, `this` in JavaScript is dynamic; we have to work around that. Since we do have lexical scoping for variables, we can utilize that: <sup><sub>[**[try it](http://jsfiddle.net/SsePz/2/)**]</sub></sup>

```
var me = this;  // store the current value of this in a variable
var loopTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    me.fadeIn();
}, 50);
```

After that's solved, you might want to look into:

1. Not using global variables to hold the fade state. Even after that fix, running two fade animations at once on different elements won't work as expected. ([Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/SsePz/3/))
2. Only setting the timeout if you need to; right now, you always set it and then clear it if you don't need it. You might want to only set it if you need it in the first place.

Comment: Beat me to it, with a clearer explanation than mine. Here's a CodePen with a working version of this code: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/mvbGh

Comment: @Paul: If you look carefully, there's a little `[try it]` before the final code block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the in depth explanation. Works perfectly and will save me a lot of trouble in the future. I am a little unclear about how I would fix the next issue you mentioned, *`Only setting the timeout if you need to; right now, you always set it and then clear it if you don't need it. You might want to only set it if you need it in the first place.`* How would you recommend auctually putting that into code. I am actually very new to OOP programming and am learning it own my own...

Comment: @Shivam: Right now, you've got the timeout-clearing code in an `if` statement with a condition of `fInFrom === 10`. If you removed the `clearTimeout` from in there and moved the `setTimeout` into an `else`, then there would be no need to clear it; you'll only set it when you want it to do another step, and `setTimeout` (as opposed to `setInterval`) will automatically clear it when it calls your function.

Comment: I have tried your recommendation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SsePz/4/) but it seems like the same issue is still happening, would you happen to know why that would be?

Comment: @Shivam: Perhaps I wasn't clear; making such a change won't fix the problem with multiple simultaneous animations — to fix that, you need to rid yourself of the global variables (but it's not as simple as moving them into the function as local variables, as then they won't be preserved between calls). Moving the `setTimeout` to `else` won't fix that; I just thought it might make your code a little clearer.